# Two observer methods that occur on same event don't work

Tags: magento-1.7, event-observer

I have 2 functions in the same Observer class: `setQuotationName` and `setShippingMethod`. They are handled at this event: `mynamespace_module_before_send_quotation`

Here's the `config.xml` part concerning these methods:

```
<mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
    <observers>
       <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
            <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
            <method>setQuotationName</method>           <!-- for quotation NAME -->
       </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
    </observers>
</mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
<mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
   <observers>
      <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
           <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
           <method>setShippingMethod</method>           <!-- for quotation SHIPPING method -->
      </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
   </observers>
</mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
```

I also tried putting the 2 `<class>` and `<method>` parts in the same event node, like this:

```
<mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
        <observers>
           <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
                <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
                <method>setQuotationName</method>           <!-- for quotation NAME -->
                <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
                <method>setShippingMethod</method>          <!-- for quotation SHIPPING method -->
           </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
        </observers>
    </mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
```

... and also having declared the `<class>` just once and then the 2 `<method>`s, but none works flawlessly. Once either one of the methods works and the other doesn't OR one of them works and everything else is broken, etc.

So, how can I declare in the config.xml 2 observer methods that are handlen upon the same event occurrence?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `events` section in the config (like anything else in the config) are merged into one big thing.
You declared your observers by using the same tag inside the `<observers>` tag for both of them. In this case both of them are merged into one single observer.
In order to have 2 observers on the same event, that key must be unique inside each event.

Here is an example

```
<some_event> <!-- event name -->
    <observers> <!-- reserved keyword "observers" -->
        <observer_name> <!-- unique name inside the event "some_event" -->
           <class>...</class> <!-- class alias  -->
           <method>....</method> <!-- method name to be executed -->
        </observer_name>
    </observers>
</some_event>
```

If you have a second observer for the event "some_event" with the same name "observer_name" the second one will override the `class` and `method` for your first one.

This is actually a feature that allows you to disable or change core observers without having to rewrite a core observer class.

In your case just rename the tag `mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation` for your second observer to something else.
Something like this:

```
<mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
    <observers>
       <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
            <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
            <method>setQuotationName</method>           <!-- for quotation NAME -->
       </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
    </observers>
</mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
<mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
   <observers>
      <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation_shipping>
           <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
           <method>setShippingMethod</method>           <!-- for quotation SHIPPING method -->
      </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation_shipping>
   </observers>
</mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
```

or better yet, you can compact it in one single event tag

```
<mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
    <observers>
       <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>
            <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
            <method>setQuotationName</method>           <!-- for quotation NAME -->
       </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation>

       <mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation_shipping>
           <class>quotationcustomize/observer</class>
           <method>setShippingMethod</method>           <!-- for quotation SHIPPING method -->
      </mynamespace_quotationcustomize_before_send_quotation_shipping>
    </observers>
</mynamespace_quotationcart_before_send_quotation>
```

Comment: Always such great answers from you! Mersi!

Comment: @marius i have a small query in magento2, we have two custom modules that are using the same event name. I would like to know order of execution how it will happen? (that means which observer file should execute 1 & then which one should execute 2nd). Please clarify

Comment: put some debug code in them and see which ones fire first. but in general, it should not be important which one fires first. they should be independent.